# Mochawesome includes javascript code instead of typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, mocha.js, supertest, mochawesome

I've written a few api tests in Typescript with mocha + supertest.
I run my tests with the 'ts' files only, the following way:

```
"api:test": "cross-env TS_NODE_PROJECT='tsconfig.api.json' mocha -r ts-node/register 'test/api/**/*.ts' --reporter mochawesome  --reporter-options overwrite=false,html=false,json=true,reportDir='test/api/report/mochawesome-report'",
```

In the generated report the code snippet of tests are included, but not from the ts files, but from the transpiled js files.
[image]

Is there any way to include the typescript code instead of the javascript?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever found a solution to his problem?

Comment: Same issue over here, any solution? @wfmn17